# Use Serializer Method Field in another Method field

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my serializer, I have a method field, that I would want to use in another method field. This will be best explained in code:

```py
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = serializers.CharField()
    analyzed_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    analyzed_analyzed_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = DataProviderModel
        fields = ["data", "analyzed_data", "analyzed_analyzed_data"]

    def get_analyzed_data(self, data):
        return data.capitalize()
    
    def get_analyzed_analyzed_data(self,  analyzed_data):
        return analyzed_data.strip()
```

---

serializers.py

```py
class DataProviderModel(models.Model):
    data = models.TextField()
```

---

models.py

So I want users to see the first step of data analysis and then analyze the same data further. Is that possible? Maybe that is something I shouldn't do?

Comment: What do you mean in terms of `"see the first step of data analysis and then analyze the same data further"`?

Comment: I am using this serializer to provide data for `provide request` with `method get`. User is seeing:

- data: "..."

- analyzed_data: "..."

- analyzed_analyzed_data: "..."

Comment: Both of the keys should have the same value? I’d ask you to explicitly show the fields instead of ‘__all__’

Comment: I have edited the post. User has access to "data", then "data" is processed for the first time and shown as "analyzed_data" then the data is processed for the second time and shown as "analyzed_analyzed_data".

Comment: I think I understood what you want. Which field belongs to the `DataProviderModel`? All of them? May you add the model as it is and what you want to do with each field?

Nevertheless, your question is very broad. `Try to add model with fields and what is the "ANALYZING" stuff you want to do with each field`. 

For example, If `data` is the data itself (from the model) like a dict that has keys and values, thus analyzed_data and analyzed_analyzed_data are other dicts that inherits from each other.

Comment: I have updated my question. We are working with `text data` only, all those fields can be represented by a `string`. The model could be as simple as that, it contains only the initial `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [to_reprensentation()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields) approach to edit the values from instance.

> .to_representation(self, value) method. This method takes the target
> of the field as the value argument, and should return the
> representation that should be used to serialize the target. The value
> argument will typically be a model instance.

In other words, you can use the to_representation() method to even add values that does not even exists into the fields from the model. Like if you want to add another field to it like `"apple":5` you can, although it does not exist in  the `self.Meta.model`.

Therefore, I took the freedom to tailor the answer like this as I do normally. Like this you have much more freedom to do whatever you want with the data without many validations from the framework.

```py
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = DataProviderModel
        fields = "__all__"

    def analyze_data(self, data):
        # do all things needed here.
        return analyzed_data

    def analyze_analyzed_data(self, analyzed_data):
        # do all things needed here.
        return analyzed_analyzed_data
     
    def to_representation(self, instance):

        analyzed_data = self.analyzed_data(instance.data)
        analyzed_analyzed_data = self.analyzed_analyzed_data(analyzed_data)

        data = {
                "data": instance.data,
                "analyzed_data": analyzed_data,
                "analyzed_analyzed_data": analyzed_analyzed_data
                }

         return data
```